# How can I observing the Apple watch "Now Playing" action?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch, watchos

I've already success for using WKAudioFilePlayer to play the song when the app in background mode. The watch "Now Playing" app can display the song information correctly.

However, I have no idea that how to observe the user action that they click the play/pause, next, prev song in "Now playing

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideo.html

In above doc, said that -

> After initiating playback of an audio file using a WKAudioFilePlayer
>   object, use that object or the WKAudioFilePlayerItem object to monitor
>   or change the state of playback. For example, you might use these
>   objects to check for errors during playback. The user can also control
>   playback using the system's Now Playing app.

so... the question is "How can I handle the action of system's Now Playing app?"